# Zend Framework 2 Update Value of ResultSet Object

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Zend framework 2 newb here so bear with me. See the code below:

```
public function setMediaToTrue($users) {
    foreach($users as $user) {
        $user->media = true;
    }
    return $users;
}
```

This method receive $users ResultSet object and update the media property to true. The problem is I can't modify the property of $users object inside iteration. Things that I have tried :
1. Use $users->current() inside iteration. example below :

```
$users->current()->media = true;
```

1. Create setMedia inside $user model and use it inside iteration:

   $user->setMedia(true); // This does not update the property either

I think the problem because ZF2 create new copy of object for each iteration. I was looking at using Hydrator but can't get my head around it.

Thanks